# UIButton in tableFooterView not responding to click event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my viewDidLoad, I have written this code:

```
UIView *footerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];        
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 40); 
[btn setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[footerView addSubview:btn];

myTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

and My selector method is:

```
- (void) onClickSelect: (UIButton*) sender
{
NSLog(@"selext");
 }
```

but when I click the button (which I have added in the table footer view), the selector method doesn't get called. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the correct frame for FooterView.Something like

```
UIView *footerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 320, 60)] autorelease];
```

Comment: Ya, got it. Thanks a lot. And 1 more thing, your name (EXE_BAD_ACCESS) is too good. :) :D